# Unable to commit to forked ngBootstrap repository

Tags: git, ng-bootstrap

Every time I try to commit I get the following error.

```
[?2004h"/Users/<Username>/repos/ng-bootstrap/.git/hooks/commit-msg" 
.git/COMMIT_E
</.git/hooks/commit-msg" .git/COMMIT_ED                                       
</.git/hooks/commit-msg" .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG 0<&- && exit || exit[?2004l

husky > npm run -s commitmsg (node v9.10.1)

/Users/<Username>/repos/ng-bootstrap/misc/validate-commit.js:93
  var incorrectLogFile = commitMsgFile.replace('COMMIT_EDITMSG', 'logs/incorrect-commit-msgs');
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<Username>/repos/ng-bootstrap/misc/validate-commit.js:93:40)
at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:690:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:666:3

husky > commit-msg hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```

It doesn't appear to me to be an issue with the hook but I am not sure, can anyone help me out?

Comment: What is the content of your hook?

Comment: It looks like you have a broken `pre-commit` hook in your repository. Take a look in the `.git/hooks` directory; do you see a file named `pre-commit` there?

Comment: There is, the remote isn't controlled by me.

The hook is intended to insure code quality but I don't think I am violating any rules.